# How to use MySQL aes_encrypt and aes_decrypt?

Tags: mysql, security, aes

I'm simply testing MySQL `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` before I start using it in my app. So I write a simple query to test it like:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('SERV92','TESTTTTTTT'),'TESTTTTTTT') AS `TEST`
```

I get an error because there are to few parameters in `AES_ENCRYPT()`
I do some research and find that my version(5.6) of MySQL does indeed take an extra parameter so I rewrite the query

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('SERV92','TESTTTTTTT',RANDOM_BYTES(16)),'TESTTTTTTT',RANDOM_BYTES(16)) AS `TEST`
```

Result:

```
+-----------+
|    TEST   |
|-----------|
|    NULL   |
+-----------+
```

Important MySQL Variables:

```
block encryption mode=aes-256-cbc
```

I'm trying to use AES 256

Comment: Hint: You're getting *random* bytes for the IV, but it should be the same bytes for both calls.

Answer (score 2):

You apparently need to use the same `init_vector` 3rd argument as this works:

```
> set @a=RANDOM_BYTES(16);
> SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('SERV92','TESTTTTTTT',@a),'TESTTTTTTT',@a) AS `TEST`;
+--------+
| TEST   |
+--------+
| SERV92 |
+--------+
```

In your case you used RANDOM_BYTES(16) twice so that different values are used in encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Why would my result be `534552563932`

Comment: huh? could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Yes, My biggest mistake was not using the same 16 bytes. Basically I copied and pasted your query and it returned one record for one column the column being `TEST` and the value of the one record under `TEST` is a number. Why would the result be a number and not the string value of 'SERV92'?

Comment: hm ... so for some strange reason you get a hex string representation of 'SERV92' back ('53'=S, 45=E ...) ... strange, no idea why ...

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the problem, `AES_DECRYPT()` returns data as a blob. Basically I just needed to tell it that it was utf8 text, as show below.

```
SET @a=RANDOM_BYTES(16); #Thanks Hartmut Holzgraefe
SELECT CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('SERV92','TESTTTTTTT',@a),'TESTTTTTTT',@a) USING utf8) AS `TEST`
+----------+
|   TEST   |
+----------+
|  SERV92  |
+----------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all byte values are also valid UTF-8 encodings. If you want text, you would need base 64 encoding.